# revtex4-1 onecolumn: Remove the extra long blanks before/after eqnarray

Tags: equations, line-breaking, columns, revtex, eqnarray

In revtex4-1 onecolumn, I find the extra-long blanks (sentence breaks) before/after eqnarray, like this

[image]

> question: How to remove the extra long blanks before/after eqnarray?

```
\documentclass[11pt, notitlepage, nofootinbib, onecolumn,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,prr,superscriptaddress,noshowpacs]{revtex4-1}
    \begin{document}

    Here here here:
    \begin{eqnarray}
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
    \end{eqnarray}
    There there there:
    \begin{eqnarray}
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
    \end{eqnarray}

    \end{document}
```

One stupid way I can do is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, notitlepage, nofootinbib, onecolumn,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,prr,superscriptaddress,noshowpacs]{revtex4-1}
    \begin{document}

    Here here here:
    \begin{eqnarray}\\[-14mm]
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
    \end{eqnarray}
    There there there:
    \begin{eqnarray}\\[-14mm]
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
    \end{eqnarray}

    \end{document}
```

which gives (this is more or less the normal line break width that I wish to have)
[image]

But this is pretty inefficient and bad looking. Comments?  Thanks!

Comment: You have a large line spacing. Also the space between two lines of ordinary text is double.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why do set both `showpacs` and `noshowpacs` as document class options?

Comment: The `revtex4-1` class uses the standard value for `\abovedisplayskip`. My opinions about this are: (1) the default value is a bit too large; (2) your expected output is typographically poor. Some other points: nobody should be using `eqnarray` nowadays; the `revtex4-2` class has been available for a few months.

Comment: >> nobody should be using eqnarray nowadays; Q: thanks. then what should we use?

Comment: @egreg, >> nobody should be using eqnarray nowadays; Q: thanks. then what should we use? – wonderich 6 hours ago

Comment: maybe related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468079/intertext-shortintertext-with-revtex-gives-large-spurious-spacing

Comment: @wonderich https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: but even if I use \begin{align} ... \end{align}, there are still a large break between lines. How can I avoid? How does \abovedisplayskip work?

Comment: As @Schrödinger'scat pointed out the issue has nothing to do with `eqnarray` or `align`. You simply have a large line spacing. You can use the class option `tightenlines` to reduce it. Note also that `prr` is not a valid option.